# How can I display multiple subreports based on an if-then-else in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

We have a report which does not contain enough data for us in the original tables. Because there is not a way to properly link all tables needed, we need to use two subreports to display the proper information. Is there a way to display subreport A if the conditions are met and display subreport B if the new conditions are met?

Comment: And what are the conditions? You can suppress a subreport just like any other field.

Comment: IF {GLAS.Source} = "PO Receipt"
THEN
{SubreportA}
ELSE
IF {GLAS.Source} = "Ap Entry"
THEN {SubreportB}

Would that work?

Thank you so much, Ryan!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two report sections, one for subreport A and one for subreport B. Suppress the section with subreport A with the formula `{GLAS.Source} <> "PO Receipt"` and similarly suppress the section with subreport B with the formula `{GLAS.Source} <> "Ap Entry"`.

Comment: I will try it and let you know how/if that works how we want!

Thanks so much, Ryan!